# Can I access the old version of Google Search Console to see crawling and indexing?

Tags: google-search-console, web-crawlers, search-engine-indexing, statistics

I remember google webmaster console had a crawl and indexing, But in new version, I couldn't find crawling or indexing. Everything is different.

Can I access to old style of google console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get to *Crawl Stats* by using the nav bar to the left. It's under the "Legacy tools and reports" section, if that's what you're referring to.

---

As far as manually indexing and crawling on a page-by-page basis, you can no longer access the old style of Google Search Console for those, you have to use the new version.

For more information on how to use the new "URL Inspection Tool" to manually crawl and index pages, see the following Google support article:

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9012289

Comment: It's only *stat*, I need to *index* and *crawl* commands.

Comment: @PersianGulf see edit